# Authenticate Vue with WebAPI using AzureAD

Tags: vuejs2, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, webapi, jwt

I am trying to query the data from [AzureAD protected WebAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-web-api) from Vue using [vue-msal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-msal).

WebApi: `58ca819e-` is webapi app id registered in AzureAD

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "ClientId": "58ca819e-",
    "TenantId": "3a0cf09b-"
  },
```

Msal plugin in main.js: `be7e77ba` is spa client app id registered in AzureAD

```
import msal from 'vue-msal'
Vue.use(msal, {
  auth: {
    clientId: 'be7e77ba-x',
    tenantId: '3a0cf09b-x',
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:8080/callback'
  },   
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
  },
});
```

In the component: `$msal.acquireToken` is called for access token on 2 scopes Microsoft Graph `user.read` and WebAPI `api://58ca819e-/access_as_user` where `58ca819e-` is WebAPI app id registed in AzureAD.

```
if (!this.$msal.isAuthenticated()) {        
      this.$msal.signIn();    
    }
    else{
      this.$msal
        .acquireToken({scopes: ["user.read", 'api://58ca819e-x/access_as_user']})
        .then((res)=>{
          console.log(res.accessToken)
          this.token = res
        })
        .catch(err=>console.error(err))
    }
```

The received access token contains only Microsoft Graph but not WebAPI scopes. The token is invalid for the WebAPI.

```
"scp": "openid profile User.Read email",
```

When only WebAPI scope is provided, the generated token containing `"scp": "access_as_user",` can access the WebAPI:

```
this.$msal.acquireToken({scopes: ['api://58ca819e-x/access_as_user']})
or
this.$msal.acquireToken({scopes: ['api://58ca819e-x/access_as_user','user.read']})
```

Looks like only 1 scope is used? Can we ask the access token for >1 scopes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No!**

A token can only correspond to one `scope`. The access token is issued according to the [api audience](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#payload-claims) you want to access, and it is unique! A token can only have one `audience`, and you cannot use multiple scopes to request access tokens.

You should put the api you want to access in the scope. For example, if you want to access MS graph api, you can put `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`. If you want to access a custom api, you can put in `api://{back-end app client api}/scope name`.

[image]